# Data-Refresh strategy in Mobile Applications

Tags: android, rest, google-cloud-messaging, refresh

I'm currently developing an mobile application and rest service. The mobile application executes lots of calls to the service even if no update is required and data didn't changed. In order to remove this overhead of rest calls I'm planning to implement GCM (Google Cloud Messaging).

My strategy would be the following:

Load all required data on application startup. When data change was recognized on server side a push notification will be sent via GCM to affected devices to make partial refreshes of data (via specific rest calls). Advantages of this would be less overhead at service side, because there are no unnecessary rest calls and a more fluid user experience in my opinion. Disadvantage is that the app is dependent on GCM Messages and that they arrive in time.

I'm unsure if this is the right strategy for this. Could someone maybe point me in the right direction and tell me if this is a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

We could use more information before answering details...

> I'm unsure if this is the right strategy for this. Could someone maybe point me in the right direction and tell me if this is a good practise?

I will consider for the sake of giving an overall answer that:

A - User is not always with the application "online", neither has network, not even a desire to have updated info at all times.

B - User is eletronicaly litterate enough to understand difficulties with the program.

With those in mind, then what would be a good approach is:

Poll relevant data, store them locally. At this stage, one would consider the relevant informations that user would have and store them, with a date flag.

Once a flag goes "old" (below your threshold), re-query that data.

Operations follow 2 directives... When observing a data, check its state, show the user if its recent or not, and if its not, poll it. If it is, if the user selects operations on it (POST mostly), re query the data.

This way, you have no static overhead, if users dont have the app on foreground. Also, should they use your "always online app", they understand that network is a necessity.

Comment: The data i mentioned will be frequently updated by users of mobile app. Parts of the app need to show the most recent data to user(voting system). Sorry, forgot to provide that information in my question. The problem is that i can't provide a flag like you suggested, because i dont know when the data should be updated.

Comment: The overal idea has not changed. During use, when the application is being executed (mainly, in the Activity), the user will be seeing only a sub-set of informations, therefore, you keep on cheking those that he see, the next expected group, and the previous seen group... this way, suppose a user is cheking movies in a cinema, if the movies are sorted by alphabet, then check current letter + previous letter and next letter.. if its sorted by area, then check cinemas data nearby etc..

Comment: Ok i think i understand. You mean calling rest service and comparing the result with the current locally stored result on device and when user performs action on outdated data perform a refresh?

Comment: Yes, however, I would create some further scenarios. For instance, if a user is cheking a group of information, try to refresh that information (so that the user does not try to edit/alter it, and then have it fail due to old information).... Also, if your program requires "up-to-date" information, have a setting that allows users to either refresh a lot of content on a given time of the day, or even have the user alter the threshold of time for the data to be updated.